# Magento 2: Not able to delete second layout in widget

Tags: javascript, magento2.4, widget, magento-framework

#### Magento 2.4

> Admin > Content > widget

After creating a new widget I have added two layouts.
When I had tried to delete the second layout then the delete button is not worked.

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EEhxFnAlPUu_-4srQGkQOP_iVtlLxIm6/view

[image: not able to delete second layout in widget]
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this issue is already registered at the Magento git community

> https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29936

After applying the below changes to my core files my issue is resolved.

> https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/29991/files

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not afraid of messing with MySQL, you can remove the offending layout update from the table `your_store.widget_instance_page`.
This should also automatically delete the associated `layout_update_id` from `your_store.widget_instance_page_layout`.